# Assembly- load xmm register to 32-register

Tags: assembly, masm, sse

I have my result in xmm0. It is one 32-bit floating number. I am trying to load it to a 32-bit register edx

```
movss dword ptr [result], xmm0
mov eax, dword ptr [result]
```

And I have weird number in eax... I thought that it is an address but it isn't because I tried to see what is behind that address.

My second idea was:

```
movd eax, xmm0
```

But it gives me the same result as the first one.
Does anyone know how to load floating number from xmm register to 32-bit register correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting - like, a rounded result, or the literal float bits interpreted as an int?

Comment: I expect the result in eax with mantissa and exponent so the literal float bits interpreted as an int

Comment: That's exactly what you get. Provide more information if you think there is an error, such as the actual contents of `xmm0` and `eax`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result converted from single-precision floating point to integer, then use

```
cvtss2si r32, xmm
```

There are other conversion instructions for e.g. converting 4 packed floats to 4 packed 32bit integers:

```
cvtps2dq xmm, xmm
```

The Intel intrinsics guide can be handy for searching by function, and of course the Intel insn ref guide has full details for everything, with an index that has summaries.  Links to those, and other essential reading like Agner Fog's guides, at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.